# Finding space used on windows NTFS mounts

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs

I have a few windows servers that I am interested in determining how much space is being used.

If a drive is mounted as a drive letter, this is pretty easy.  But in several cases I see volumes that are mounted only as folders.  When it's mounted this way, Explorer just shows me the size of the disk, not the used/free within that volume.

I've poked around explorer windows, `dir` commands, `df` from within cygwin, volume manager, and a couple of others.  I feel I'm missing some obvious command that would show this.

Anyone have a pointer for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Computer Management, Storage.

As Techie2007 says in the commentary: run diskmgmt.msc to load just the Disk Management console (thanks!!!)

Example:

[image]

Comment: And/or run `diskmgmt.msc` to load just the Disk Management console.

Comment: This seems to work for all my systems without VxVM installed.  Those are weirder.  Data still visible here, but it doesn't make sense.